# Calling a js function throught html is causing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load my code compares user position against coordinates of each tram stop and chooses the closest one which works absolutely fine.

The problem is with `onchange=tram_stops(this.value)` as when I change the value I am getting an error:

> SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'tram_stops'

Does anyone know how to sort this out?

```
@extends('master') @section('title', 'Trams')
@section('extrafiles')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/tram.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
@section('content')
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Metrolink Times</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tram_stops">Select a station:</label>
        <form id="tram_stops">
          <select id="tram_dropdown" class="form-control" onchange="tram_stops(this.value);">
            @foreach($entities as $entity)
              <option data-lng="{{ $entity->_geoloc->lng }}" data-lat="{{ $entity->_geoloc->lat }}"  value="{{empty($entity->_geoloc->slug) ? 'no-slug' : $entity->_geoloc->slug}}">{{$entity->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="display">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var user_lat;
  var user_lng;
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    var distanceArray = [];
    var slugArray = [];
    user_lat = position.coords.latitude;
    user_lng = position.coords.longitude;
    $("option").each(function() {
      var unit = "K";
      var tram_lat = $(this).attr("data-lat");
      var tram_lng = $(this).attr("data-lng");
      var slug = $(this).attr("value");
      var radlat1 = Math.PI * tram_lat / 180
      var radlat2 = Math.PI * user_lat / 180
      var theta = tram_lng - user_lng;
      var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180
      var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
      dist = Math.acos(dist)
      dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
      if (unit == "K") {
        dist = dist * 1.609344
      }
      if (unit == "N") {
        dist = dist * 0.8684
      }
      slugArray.push(slug);
      distanceArray.push(dist);
    });
    var closest = Math.min(...distanceArray);
    var index = (distanceArray.indexOf(closest));
    var slug = (slugArray[index]);
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("item") === null) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("item", slug);
      timeout();
    } else {
      timeout();
    }
  }
});

function timeout() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var tram_val = sessionStorage.getItem("item");
    tram_stops(tram_val);
    $("#tram_dropdown").val(tram_val);
  }, 30000);
}

function tram_stops(tram_value) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("item", tram_value);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/tramsearch/' + tram_value,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#display").html(data);
      var tram_value = tram_value;
    },
    error: function(data) {
    },
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
  timeout();
}
```

Comment: This is not plain HTML

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**

This happens if you have a function in javascript of the same name as any HTML element id. In your case, `tram_stops` is, you have form id and a function of this name.

```
 <form id="tram_stops">
```

**Solution**

Change form id or change the function name or attach onchange event dynamically using jQuery:

```
$("body").on("change", "#tram_dropdown", function(){/*Your Code*/});
```

Comment: that was the case, weird that it was working before, now I get: 'tram_stops' is not defined

Comment: You could try binding the event through code instead of inline, as `N. Ivanov` suggested if you still have issues after fixing the naming collision.

Comment: That seems not to trigget the function when I attach onchange event dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an `onchange=""` attribute, you would be better off listening for an event. Here is an example of how to do it:

```
$("body").on("change", "#tram_dropdown", function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("item", tram_value);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tramsearch/' + tram_value,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          $("#display").html(data);
          var tram_value = tram_value;
        },
        error: function(data) {
        },
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    timeout();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this way, doesn't actually trigget the function

Comment: how no? On each change of your `<select>` tag this will be executed. Check your code for errors. but the event should be fired.

Answer (score -1):

Change onchange function to:

```
 onchange="tram_stops();"
```

Then get the value using jquery  like this:

```
var tram_value = $('#tram_dropdown').val();
```